# Prove Liouville theorem without using mean value property

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

How can I prove the following Liouville theorem without using the mean value property?

> If $u$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|D u|^2 dx \leq C$ for some $C > 0$, then $u$ is constant.

The proof that I know indeed uses the mean value property for harmonic functions.

Comment: Could you not write: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|Du(x)|^2 \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (-\Delta f(x)) \overline{f(x)} \, dx = 0$. Which then implies that $Du(x) = 0$ and so $u$ is constant. I think the only difficulty is justifying the integration by parts.

Comment: @UtilityMaximiser : If the derivative vanishes, then the function is constant.  Doesn't that proof (even in one dimension) use MVT?

Answer (score 1):

Let me first say that the statement $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \vert Du \vert^2 d x = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u \Delta u d x$$ which is in the comments is false - integration by parts only works on bounded sets. As a simple counter example to the above claim take $u(x) = x_1$.

One way to prove this for $n>2$ without the Mean Value Formula makes use of a monotonicity formula. This is kind of similar to the Mean Value Formula in spirit (you can think of the MVF as a monotonicity formula where the monotone quantity is in fact constant).

Let $B_r$ be a ball of radius $r$. Then $$\phi :  r\mapsto \frac{1}{r^{n-2}} \int_{B_r} \vert Du \vert^2 d x $$ is nondecreasing.

Observe that \begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dr} \bigg ( \frac{1}{r^{n-2}} \int_{B_r} \vert Du \vert^2 d x\bigg ) &= - \frac{n-2}{r^{n-1}} \int_{B_r} \vert Du \vert^2 d x + \frac 1 {r^{n-2}} \int_{\partial B_r} \vert Du \vert^2 d \mathcal{H}^{n-1}.
\end{align*} It is possible to show that for harmonic functions \begin{equation}(n-2)\int_{B_r} \vert Du \vert^2 d x = r \int_{\partial B_r} \vert Du \vert^2 - 2 \bigg ( \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu }\bigg )^2d \mathcal{H}^{n-1}. \label{eq:2} \end{equation} (To prove this calculate $ \int_{B_r} \mathrm{div} (x \vert Du \vert^2) dx $ in two different ways: first by using the divergence theorem and secondly by expanding $\mathrm{div} (x \vert Du \vert^2)$ then applying integration by parts to one of the terms. Another way to prove this is using Neother's Theorem, see Chapter 8.6.2  in *Partial Differnetial Equations* by Lawrence C. Evans.) Hence, it follows $$\frac{d}{dr} \bigg ( \frac{1}{r^{n-2}} \int_{B_r} \vert Du \vert^2 d x\bigg ) = \frac 2 {r^{n-2}} \int_{\partial B_r} \bigg ( \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu }\bigg )^2d \mathcal{H}^{n-1} \geqslant 0.$$ However, by our assumption $$ 0 \leqslant \phi(r) \leqslant \frac{C}{r^{n-2}} \to 0$$ as $r \to \infty$ provided $n>2$. Hence, $\phi(r) = 0$ for all $r >0$, so $u$ is a constant. The only issue with this is it doesn't apply to the case $n=2$.